# Bootstrap Responsiveness

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have an upcoming test in which I will be given a one-page design that I will be asked to re-create in one hour using HTML and CSS.  The use of Bootstrap is also encouraged, and "bonus points" will be given for making the page responsive.

I am a little confused by the last part of this question, because I have read that Bootstrap is responsive in and of itself.  If this is true, would I get "bonus points" for simply utilizing Bootstrap, or is there more to it than this (i.e. I still create my own responsive nav menu within my self-created CSS file / there is some way to edit or personalize Bootstrap's inherited responsiveness)?

Thank you!

Comment: Yep, you can create a .css file and place link to it after link to .css bootstrap file. In your .css file, you can use @media to handle responsiveness

Answer (score 0):

Check out the introduction docs for Bootstrap:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/

It might be a bit much but when you spend a night experimenting and reading, you'll be able to do great things with it

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the navbar is responsive on its own but if you want to be sure to get bonus points, you might want to change the behaviour of certain columns based on the screen size.

You can find more about that [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#responsive-classes)